# Calculating product of numbers using do while

Tags: c#, loops, product, do-while

I'm new to coding and trying my best but I got stuck. Again.
So. I need to calculate the product of some random numbers using do while.
You type the numbers and when you type x, the loop needs to close showing the result. If you ONLY type x, it needs to show "1".

I can't manage to only show "1" when you type "x".

I have this:

```csharp
int product = 1;

Console.WriteLine();
String input = Console.ReadLine();

do
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(input);
    product = product * n;
    input = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!input.ToLower().Equals("x"));
            
Console.WriteLine(product);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` and `while` breaks in the start of the loops and `do while` break at the end, sometimes you have to break it the middle (here after the input was entered, if it's `x`) and before the accumulation.

The best way to manage this is an infinite loop `for(;;)` or `while(true)` and uses of `break`:

```csharp
var product = 1;

for(;;)
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input is null || input.Equals("x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        break;

    product *= Convert.ToInt32(input);
}

Console.WriteLine(product);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Or you can try to make it fit (mostly double calls to `ReadLine`).

### A `for` version that looks ugly:

```csharp
var product = 1;
for (var input = Console.ReadLine(); input != "x"; input = Console.ReadLine())
{
    product *= int.Parse(input);
}

Console.WriteLine(product);
Console.ReadLine();
```

### A `while` version:

```csharp
var product = 1;
var input = Console.ReadLine();

while (!input.ToLower().Equals("x"))
{
    product *= Convert.ToInt32(input);
    input = Console.ReadLine();
} 

Console.WriteLine(product);
Console.ReadLine();
```

### Another `while` version that avoid `ReadLine` at multiple places:

```csharp
var product = 1;

string input;

// an affectation actually evaluate to the value affected
// avoid this since it's not easily readable (= and == mismatch)
while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "x")
{
    product *= Convert.ToInt32(input);
} 

Console.WriteLine(product);
Console.ReadLine();
```

### A `do while` version:

I add it because it's in the question title, otherwise I didn't consider it a good solution.
Based on [yassinMi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19399896) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72860059/361177).

```csharp
var product = 1;
var input = "1";
do
{
    product *= int.Parse(input);
    input = Console.ReadLine();
} while (input != "x");

Console.WriteLine(product);
Console.ReadLine();
```

### A Linq version:

```csharp
var product = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)          // many elements
                        .Select(_ => Console.ReadLine()) // discard them and take the console input                        
                        .TakeWhile(s => s != "x")        // stop on 'x'
                        .Select(int.Parse)               // parse to int
                        .Aggregate(1, (a, b) => a * b);  // accumulate from 1 and by making the product

Console.WriteLine(product);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Very nice answer! It is very well explained and all methods are covered. Make sure to explain everything, the author of the question is a beginner in C#, might not know what is Linq.

Comment: @catalin-stoia I added a `do while` example since you seems to really need this flavor.

Answer (score 0):

a simple fix: change the line

```
String input = Console.ReadLine();
```

to

```
String input = "1";
```

otherwise you would use the while loop, or add extra if statement..

Comment: That does not solve the problem, that the _op_ did a not so good job describing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C#!

Your issue is most likely due to an error while converting a value. You are trying to convert "x" to `int`, but "x" is a letter, which cannot be converted to a number.

## Cause of the issue

The problem of this program is that you are trying to convert a letter to a number. This is not possible in real life, and less possible in programming! A computer is not able to convert a number to a letter, unless you are explaining to it how, or if your handle the error properly.

The following line:

```cs
int n = Convert.ToInt32(input);
```

...Does not check for what has been entered. `Convert.ToInt32()` will throw an exception if the `string?` (From `Console.ReadLine()`) could not be converted.

## The fix

To fix this issue, you need to handle the input of the user. Literally anything is accepted by `Console.ReadLine()` but you want a value that can be converted to a `int`.
The `int` type has a built-in function to convert a value without throwing an exception if it couldn't be converted, instead, it returns a `bool` (Either `true` or `false`).

So the following changes need to be brought to your program:

```cs
int product = 1;
string ? input;

do {
  input = Console.ReadLine();

  // Try to parse to integer, if it couldn't be parsed to integer, continue.
  if (!int.TryParse(input, out int n)) {
    continue;
  }

  product = product * n;

} while (!input.Equals("x", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

Console.WriteLine(product);

// End of the program
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit the program.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

## Trying to parse a string to an integer

The method `int.TryParse(string? input, out int output);` allows you to try to convert a `string` to a `int`.

If the method fails, instead of throwing an `Exception`, it will returns `false`.

### Getting the output value

The output value can be obtained from `out int output`, `out` allows you to output a value from a function.

The logic would be that if `int.TryParse(...)` returns `true`, the value can be used, otherwise you can `continue`.

The `continue` statement tells your loop that the current loop should be skipped and goes to the next one (= At the beginning of your loop).

## Other changes

I've brought to your program some changes to make it more readable and easier to edit.

Firstly, you'd want to use `Equals(input, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` instead of `ToLowerCase()`, the result is the same and it is cleaner!

Also, you can directly ask the input within your `while` loop since this will be repeated each time, you just need to position it correctly so the value can be verified.

### Final program

[image: The program now works perfectly!]

Answer (score 0):

```
        ConsoleKeyInfo continueProgram = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
        ConsoleKeyInfo continueInput = new ConsoleKeyInfo();

        List<int> products = new List<int>();

        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            
            do
            {
                Console.Write("\nPlease enter new number . . . ");
                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
                {
                    products.Add(result);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nNew Product Added!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou have entered a value that is not an integer!\n");
                }

                Console.Write("\nDo you want to enter an other value (press Y) or any key to exit . . . ");
                continueInput = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            while (continueInput.Key == ConsoleKey.Y);

            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (var item in products)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("\n\nPress 'Y' to continue or any other key to exit! . . . ");
            continueProgram = Console.ReadKey();

        } while (continueProgram.Key == ConsoleKey.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Console.ReadLine()` gets called twice before checking for `x`. The first input gets eaten up.

What you need to do is inside the loop ask and process the input, and exit the loop when the condition is met.

One way of doing this is by keeping a `boolean` value called `done` indicating when to exit the loop'

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int product = 1;
        bool done = false;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number or 'x' to calculate result.");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            done = input.ToLower() == "x";
            if (int.TryParse(input, out int value))
            {
                product *= value;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input ignored.");
            }
        } while (!done);

        Console.WriteLine($"The product is {product}");

    }
```

Another more succinct way is to use the `break;` statement

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int product = 1;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number or 'x' to calculate result.");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input.ToLower() == "x")
            {
                // this exits the loop
                break;
            }
            if (int.TryParse(input, out int value))
            {
                product *= value;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input ignored.");
            }
        } while (true);

        Console.WriteLine($"The product is {product}");

    }
```

Also, it is recommended to use `int.TryParse(string, out integer)`  for better handling weird user inputs instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`. See the pattern above on how it is used.